# Handle file chooser android 6.0 webview

Tags: android, file, android-studio, webview, event-handling

I am new in android and now try to develope web application. I have use several days to make input type file work perfectly in webview. Until I follow and use this code to handle file chooser in webview.

[enter link description here](https://www.opengeeks.me/2015/08/filechooser-and-android-webview/)

When I use AVD Nexus with gingerbeard and click input type file, it can show two option (camera or gallery).
The probelm is when I use AVD Nexus with 6.0 and click input type file, it open file manager without showing option camera or gallery.
I want to show input option dialog every time user click input type file.

How can I do this? Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this for android 5.0 and above

```
private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private Context mContext=YourActivity.this; 
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 111; 

// For Android 5.0

public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
{
    //  Log.d(TAG,"ShowFileChooser For Android 5.0 ");
    if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
    }
    mFilePathCallback = filePath;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Log.d(TAG,"ShowFileChooser For Android 5.0 SDK_INT>=23 chk permission");
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            //Log.d(TAG,"ShowFileChooser For Android 5.0 in IF  SDK_INT>=23 permission grant");
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = Constant.create_file();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    // Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        // Log.d(TAG,"ShowFileChooser For Android 5.0 in else SDK_INT>=23");
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = Constant.create_file();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                // Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
    return true;
}
```

Check permissions for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = Constant.create_file();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
            } else {
                Patient_appointment.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is mContext? And Value for REQUEST_CAMERA? My actvity name is InventoryDataEditor.

Comment: Context mContext=InventoryDataEditor.this;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 111;

Comment: After giving permission it still showing toast with Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1):

whoever want file uploading functionality in their web view client above API 21, then follow below link it is much simpler than above answer:-

https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser/issues/253